# How to make a TreeView expanded by default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, treeview

By default a @mui TreeView has all its nodes collapsed.

I want it to have all its nodes expanded by default, and I can't find how to do that.

My attempts were to use a method I called handleExpandAll but it doesn't work, the navigator says it renders too many times. Which is weird because without the call it seemingly renders 1 time, but with it it renders an indefinite amount of times.

Maybe one of you guys could help me.

For now my code looks like this :

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import classes from "./TreeNavigation.module.css";
import TreeView from "@mui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight";
import CustomTreeItem from "../../ui/CustomTreeItem/CustomTreeItem.js";
import { apiStates } from "../Leases/useLeases.js";
import LoadingDiv from "../../ui/LoadingDiv/LoadingDiv.js";

function TreeNavigation(props) {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const handleSelect = (event, nodeId) => {
    props.onItemSelected(nodeId);
  };

  const handleToggle = (event, nodeIds) => {
    setExpanded(nodeIds);
  };

  const handleExpandAll = (length) => {
    setExpanded((oldExpanded) => [...Array(length).keys()]);
  };

  const data = props.data;

  const renderTree = (nodes) => (
    <CustomTreeItem key={nodes.id} nodeId={nodes.id} label={nodes.name}>
      {Array.isArray(nodes.children)
        ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node))
        : null}
    </CustomTreeItem>
  );

  switch (data.state) {
    case apiStates.ERROR:
      return <p>ERROR: {data.error || "General error"}</p>;
    case apiStates.SUCCESS:
      const batimentsTreeViews = data.data.map((bat) => {
        var b = [];
        for (const key in bat) {
          b = {
            id: key,
            ...bat[key],
          };
        }
        return renderTree(b);
      });

      handleExpandAll(data.data.length);

      return (
        <TreeView
          aria-label="controlled"
          defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
          expanded={expanded}
          selected={props.selectedId}
          onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
          onNodeSelect={handleSelect}
          sx={{
            flexGrow: 1,
            width: "100%",
            maxWidth: "none",
            overflowY: "auto",
          }}
        >
          {batimentsTreeViews}
        </TreeView>
      );
    default:
      return <LoadingDiv />;
  }
}

export default TreeNavigation;
```

Answer (score 0):

did you check with following way?

```
 const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState([...Array(length).keys()]);
```

default Mui treeview expands all with this way.

[image: Edit ControlledTreeView Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: Problem is that at the moment I call this class I don't have a prop called length, as the array will be constructed in the switch. (the method handleExpandAll you see in my code was just a failed attempt to make it work)